# CSS class for basic button is not being rendered

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

[image: Picture of HTML]

All,

I am developing a CSS class for a button.  But the button is not showing up when I check my Ruby html page.  The html link is rendering but not my box.  Can anyone point out what is missing or why this is occurring?

**CSS code from welcome.scss.css file**:

```
p#index-title
  {
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 15px;
   color: blue;
  }

.posts
  {
   border: solid;
   margin: 5px;
   padding: 5px;
   height: 200px;
   }

section
 {
   background:  #5998ff;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 5px;
   margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
   padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
 }

 .social_btn
  {
   display: block;
   height: 100px;
   width: 300px;
   background: #34696f;
   border: 2px solid rgba(33, 68, 72, 0.59);
   }
```

**Code from about.html.erb file:**

```
<h1>About myapp</h1>
<p>Created by: Me</p>

<%= link_to "Follow me", "https://twitter.com", class: "social_btn"%>
```

Comment: the file name should be welcome.css.scss instead of welcome.scss.css

Comment: Perhaps a demo with the HTML of the button would be useful becuase it should work at is - http://jsfiddle.net/qz2nzgag/

Comment: added screenshot.  Its just showing the link.

Comment: Do you have your .css file linked to your .html?

Comment: @IkoTikashi yes I'm calling the social-btn class that is in the welcome.scss file from within the about.html.erb file.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: Not really (I think ;) ), do you have `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" ...` in your source when you view the page?

Comment: Yes all of this already within the Rails app when you deploy it.  We don't have to specifically write that.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
<%= link_to "Follow me", "https://twitter.com", class: "social_btn"%>
```

To this:

```
<%= link_to "Follow me", "https://twitter.com", :class => "social_btn" %>
```

And changing:

```
background: #34696f;
```

To this:

```
background-color: #34696f;
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I got the same thing, the box isn't showing.  I'll upload a picture quickly.

Comment: I added the picture of what is showing now.  It has to be something in my scss file I'm thinking?

Comment: I'm still experimenting around with your codes but do try the second part of my answer which I updated just now.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I just tried that too and it's still not bringing back the button.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get the solution to why my CSS class wasn't being picked up in my welcome.scss file within Rails.  It needed to be within my application.scss file that contains my @import bootstrap.  When I get more details on why, I will come back and update this answer more thoroughly for colleagues with similar issues.

Comment: The research I used was to right click on my web page and do Inspect Element from within Google Chrome.  From their I saw it wasn't picking up my class at all, so it definitely was in the wrong css file.  My welcome controller contained the functions for the about.html.erb view, so logically the CSS class should have been in the welcome.scss file.  Will let you guys know of my research.